# Write a query join sum groupby in laravel

Tags: laravel, join, sum

Please help me write query.
I have 2 table: "projects" and "debts"
"debts" table have

```
id | project_id | currency_list | total
1  | 1          | 1             | 1000
2  | 1          | 2             | 500
3  | 2          | 1             | 1000
4  | 2          | 2             | 500
...
```

I need write query to take 1000 rows from projects and SUM all "total" with group by "currency_list"

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: you want take sum() of  where total is 1000 or where project_id ?

Comment: No. I want take all rows from "projects"  and sum "total"  group by "currency_list" from "debts". But whereIn not work because in "projects" i have around 1000000 rows. In view blade i use pagination, but i need know sum total

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hey i tried for you its hope working  :)
First you should have tow models for tables
In your Project model call like this

```
    public function debts(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Debt','project_id')->selectRaw('debts.*,sum(total) as sum')->groupBy('currency_list');
   }
```

and call this in your controller

```
$projects = Project::with('debts')->get()->toArray();
```

check your **dd($projects)** as **array**

EDIT : Use this in your controller function

```
$projects = DB::table('projects')
            ->join('debts', 'projects.id', '=', 'debts.projects_id')
            ->select('projects.*','debts.*', DB::raw('sum(total) as sum'))
            ->groupBy('currency_list')
            ->get();
```

then in your view use

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
{
{{$project->sum}}
}
```

Comment: Dear friend. Thanks a lot for your help, but how i can get total sum from all need project? :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

App/Project

```
public function getDebts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Debt');
}
```

Controller

```
use App\Project;

public function getProjects(Project $project ) 
{        
    $all =  $project->with(['getDebts'=>function($query){
                $query->selectRaw('*,sum(total) as sum')
                      ->groupBy('currency_list');
            }])->take(1000);
}
```

Comment: Nice, but i need SUM 'total' in all projects :)