# Why is MySQL SUM query only returning one row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I am trying to create a MySQL query to return the sum of all statement balances for each account in my DB. The query looks like this:

```
SELECT SUM(balance), handle FROM statement_versions
INNER JOIN statements ON statement_versions.statement_id = statements.id
INNER JOIN accounts ON statements.account_id = accounts.id;
```

When I do this, it returns only one row with one summed balance and one account (account with ID 1). What I want is to return all accounts with their summed statement balance. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to group by something, probably `handle` (I presume that is related to the account id?), otherwise MySQL will `SUM` **all** the values selected from your `JOIN`. Adding a `GROUP BY` clause makes the `SUM` happen for each distinct value of the column in the `GROUP BY`. Change your query to:

```
SELECT SUM(balance), handle FROM statement_versions
INNER JOIN statements ON statement_versions.statement_id = statements.id
INNER JOIN accounts ON statements.account_id = accounts.id
GROUP BY handle;
```

If `handle` is not related to `accounts.id` and you want to get the results grouped by `accounts.id`, change the query to:

```
SELECT SUM(balance), accounts.id FROM statement_versions
INNER JOIN statements ON statement_versions.statement_id = statements.id
INNER JOIN accounts ON statements.account_id = accounts.id
GROUP BY accounts.id;
```

Comment: Sweet thank you! I'm actually trying to figure out how to translate this into Laravel query builder, but thought if I got the underlying query correct I'd be able to do so. I was wrong haha.

Comment: Well at least this should be the correct underlying query! [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39369044/write-a-query-join-sum-groupby-in-laravel) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46641312/laravel-5-inner-join-and-group-by-query-syntax-error) might help with the laravel part.

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting an error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'statement_versions.balance' in 'field list' (SQL: select sum(`statement_versions`.`balance`) as aggregate from `accounts`)`, so I'm not sure what is going on. It seems for some reason the joins aren't structured properly or something.

Comment: @hoolakoola is this from your laravel version? You should ask another question so that some laravel experts will see it.